# Progress Report for Long-Running Queries via API.ai?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a Google Assistant agent running through API.ai with webhooks to my nodejs service. The timeout is 5seconds but I have a query that takes a little longer. Is there a way to say "Please wait while I find that for you" without hanging up the phone?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any way to get around the timeout.

I think the only way to hack it would be to set a timeout for ~4 seconds and then use `assistant.ask()` to ask something like "Could you wait a second while I find this out for you?" And then once the user responds, you could check if the response has finished.

It's really messy, and not a great user experience, but as far as I know there's no way to say something that doesn't expect a user's response without ending the conversation.